# What is the best way to chop a string into chunks of a given length in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, chunking

I have been looking for an elegant and efficient way to chunk a string into substrings of a given length in Ruby.

So far, the best I could come up with is this:

```
def chunk(string, size)
  (0..(string.length-1)/size).map{|i|string[i*size,size]}
end

>> chunk("abcdef",3)
=> ["abc", "def"]
>> chunk("abcde",3)
=> ["abc", "de"]
>> chunk("abc",3)
=> ["abc"]
>> chunk("ab",3)
=> ["ab"]
>> chunk("",3)
=> []
```

You might want `chunk("", n)` to return `[""]` instead of `[]`.  If so, just add this as the first line of the method:

```
return [""] if string.empty?
```

Would you recommend any better solution?

**Edit**

Thanks to Jeremy Ruten for this elegant and efficient solution: [edit: NOT efficient!]

```
def chunk(string, size)
    string.scan(/.{1,#{size}}/)
end
```

**Edit**

The string.scan solution takes about 60 seconds to chop 512k into 1k chunks 10000 times, compared with the original slice-based solution which only takes 2.4 seconds.

Comment: Your original solution is about as efficient and elegant as possible: there's no need to inspect each character of the string to know where to chop it, nor any need to turn the whole thing into an array and then back again.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Use `String#scan`:

```
>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.scan(/.{4}/)
=> ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx"]
>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.scan(/.{1,4}/)
=> ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx", "yz"]
>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.scan(/.{1,3}/)
=> ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwx", "yz"]
```

Comment: Ok, now this is excellent!  I knew there had to be a better way.  Thanks a lot Jeremy Ruten.

Comment: def chunk(string, size); string.scan(/.{1,#{size}}/); end

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid now. I've never even bothered to check how scan worked.

Comment: Be careful with this solution; this is a regexp, and the `/.` bit of it means it will include all characters EXCEPT newlines `\n`.  If you want to include newlines, use `string.scan(/.{4}/m)`

Comment: What a clever solution! I love regexps but I wouldn't have though of using the quantifier for this purpose. Thank you Jeremy Ruten

Comment: Is this efficient?

Comment: Won't work with big sizes. `too big number for repeat range: /.{1,240000}/m`

Answer (score 24):

Here is another way to do it:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars.to_a.each_slice(3).to_a.map {|s| s.to_s }
```

Or,

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join)
```

Either:

```
=> ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwx", "yz"]
```

Comment: Alternatively: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join)`

Comment: I like this one because it works on strings that contain newlines.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Using scan might drop last token if length won't match _pattern_.

Comment: Finbarr's alternative returned the output in this answer for me (one array with 9 string objects, max length 3). The code in the answer itself is returning 8 arrays of 3 letters each and a final one with two: `["y", "z"]`. I'm on Ruby 3.0.1, fwiw.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the most efficient solution if you know your string is a multiple of chunk size

```
def chunk(string, size)
    (string.length / size).times.collect { |i| string[i * size, size] }
end
```

and for parts

```
def parts(string, count)
    size = string.length / count
    count.times.collect { |i| string[i * size, size] }
end
```

Comment: Your string doesn't have to be a multiple of chunk size if you replace `string.length / size` with `(string.length + size - 1) / size` -- this pattern is common in C code that has to deal with integer truncation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another one solution for slightly different case, when processing large strings and there is no need to store all chunks at a time. In this way it stores single chunk at a time and performs much faster than slicing strings:

```
io = StringIO.new(string)
until io.eof?
  chunk = io.read(chunk_size)
  do_something(chunk)
end
```

Comment: For very large strings, this is _by far_ the **best way to do it**. This will avoid reading the entire string into memory and getting `Errno::EINVAL` errors like `Invalid argument @ io_fread` and `Invalid argument @ io_write`.

Answer (score 6):

I made a little test that chops about 593MB data into 18991 32KB pieces.
Your slice+map version ran for at least 15 minutes using 100% CPU before I pressed ctrl+C. This version using String#unpack finished in 3.6 seconds:

```
def chunk(string, size)
  string.unpack("a#{size}" * (string.size/size.to_f).ceil)
end
```

Comment: How would you recommend handling UTF8 strings? (the "a" specifier in unpack doesn't seem to work very well with UTF8)

Answer (score 1):

```
test.split(/(...)/).reject {|v| v.empty?}
```

The reject is necessary because it otherwise includes the blank space between sets. My regex-fu isn't quite up to seeing how to fix that right off the top of my head.

Comment: the scan aproach will forget about non matched caracteres, ie: if u try with a 10 length string slice on 3 parts, you will have 3 parts and 1 element will be dropped, your aproach don't do that, so its best.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution which takes into account the last part of the string which could be less than the chunk size:

```
def chunk(inStr, sz)  
  return [inStr] if inStr.length < sz  
  m = inStr.length % sz # this is the last part of the string
  partial = (inStr.length / sz).times.collect { |i| inStr[i * sz, sz] }
  partial << inStr[-m..-1] if (m % sz != 0) # add the last part 
  partial
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there some other constraints you have in mind?  Otherwise I'd be awfully tempted to do something simple like

```
[0..10].each {
   str[(i*w),w]
}
```

Comment: I don't really have any constraint, apart from having something simple, elegant and efficient.  I like your idea, but would you mind translating it into a method please?  The [0..10] would probably become slightly more complex.

Comment: I fixed my example to use str[i*w,w] instead of str[i*w...(i+1)*w]. Tx

Comment: This should be (1..10).collect rather than [0..10].each. [1..10] is an array consisting of one element -- a range. (1..10) is the range itself. And +each+ returns the original collection that it's called on ([1..10] in this case) rather than the values returned by the block. We want +map+ here.

Answer (score 0):

Just `text.scan(/.{1,4}/m)` resolves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I personally followed the idea of [user8556428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029194/1353549), to avoid the costly intermediate values that most proposals introduce, and to avoid modifying the input string.  And I want to be able to use it as a generator (for instance to use `s.each_slice.with_index`).

My use case is really about bytes, not characters.  In the case of character-size, strscan is a great solution.

```rb
class String
    # Slices of fixed byte-length.  May cut multi-byte characters.
    def each_slice(n = 1000, &block)
        return if self.empty?

        if block_given?
            last = (self.length - 1) / n
            (0 .. last).each do |i|
                yield self.slice(i * n, n)
            end
        else
            enum_for(__method__, n)
        end
    end
end


p "abcdef".each_slice(3).to_a # => ["abc", "def"]   
p "abcde".each_slice(3).to_a  # => ["abc", "de"]    
p "abc".each_slice(3).to_a    # => ["abc"]          
p "ab".each_slice(3).to_a     # => ["ab"]           
p "".each_slice(3).to_a       # => []
```